# python regular expression exclude from match string

Tags: python, regex

I have 3 strings

```
a ="keep the your pass ABCDEFG other text"
b ="your pass: TESTVALUE other text"
c ="no pass required other text"
```

I want to get capital values after pass, like this

```
re.match(r'.*\spass:?\s([a-zA-Z]+).*',a,re.I).group(1)
re.match(r'.*\spass:?\s([a-zA-Z]+).*',b,re.I).group(1)
```

but I want to exclude "no pass", which is I don't want re to match to c string, how do I do that?

---

Solution: Thanks eyquem and ovgolovin

I will take eyquem's suggestion of re.search('no\s+pass|pass:?\s+([A-Z]+)')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

for x in ("keep the your pass ABCDEFG other text",
          "your pass: TESTVALUE other text",
          "no pass required other text"):
    print re.search('no\s+pass|pass:?\s+([A-Z]+)',x).group(1)
A-Z]+)'
```

result

```
ABCDEFG
TESTVALUE
None
```

Comment: Nice.  I was hoping to use a re.findall for something similar, but it doesn't use group(x).  Hrm.

Answer (score 1):

It's [not OK](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html#match-versus-search) to use `match` here. It's preferable to use `search` for such cases.

```
re.search(r'(?<!no\s)pass:?\s+([A-Z]+)',a).group(1)
```

It would be better to write it this way:

```
re.search(r'(?<!no\s*)pass:?\s+([A-Z]+)',a).group(1)
```

, but unfortunatelly the current version of regex engine doesn't support infinite lookbehinds.

Comment: @user976557 Please, read why it's preferable to use `search`, not `match` (I provided the link).

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to first , filter everything which doesn't contains 'no pass' and then search for pass. Doing two steps might seem a bit heavy but you will avoid lots of problems by doing it this way. You are trying to solve two problems at the same time (and apparently you are struggling to do it) so just separate the two problems.